# Ethereum Dos fork

Tags: ether, hardforks

Yesterday the Ethereum project made a fork. Was it a soft or hard fork? How did the attacker perform his attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question it was a [hardFork](https://fork.codetract.io/). for the second i suggest you to read the related post on the ethereum blog :

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/ethereum-network-currently-undergoing-dos-attack/
https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/transaction-spam-attack-next-steps/

where they explain how the attacker exploit an EVM opcode to perform his attack.

> the network was attacked by a transaction spam attack that repeatedly
>   called the EXTCODESIZE opcode (see trace sample here), thereby
>   creating blocks that take up to ~20-60 seconds to validate due to the
>   ~50,000 disk fetches needed to process the transaction. The result of
>   this was a ~2-3x reduction in the rate of block creation while the
>   attack was taking place;